# Detect file streaming finished and ready to play with avplayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am playing audio file from remote server with avplayer. When i play this, first avplayer stream from the url and then play the file. Now I just want to detect when file streaming is finished and started to play.

Here is my code:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

player = AVPlayer(url: down_url)
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
player.volume = 1.0
player.play()


override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "rate" {
        if player.rate > 0 {
            print("player started")
        }
    }
}
```

I used this code to detect but it print "player started" only once when avplayer started to streaming. But i can't detect when avplayer started to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register as an observer of the player item's status property

```
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), options: [.old, .new], context: &playerItemContext)
```

and this method will be call

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    // Only handle observations for the playerItemContext
    guard context == &playerItemContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }


    // Observer for Player status
    if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status) {
        let status: AVPlayerItem.Status
        if let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber {
            status = AVPlayerItem.Status(rawValue: statusNumber.intValue)!
        } else {
            status = .unknown
        }

        // Switch over status value
        switch status {
        case .readyToPlay:
            // Player item is ready to play.
            player.play()
            playerControlsView.setPlayerControlsReady()
        case .failed:
            // Player item failed. See error.
            print("Fail")
        case .unknown:
            // Player item is not yet ready.
            print("unknown")
        }
    }

}
```

Add Observer to monitor when the player Finish playing

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
```

This method will call when player finish playing

```
@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification){
        print("Finished Playing")
}
```

And Don't forget to remove the Observer when your done with player

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```